# showing that $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let

$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $y \le 0$, $y \ge x^2$  } \\[2ex]
1, & \text{if $0 \lt y \lt x^2$ }  \\
\end{cases}$$

Show that $f(x,y) \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ along any straight line through the origin.

For any straight line passing through the origin looks like $y =mx$, as $(x,mx) \to (0,0)$, $x^2+m^2x^2 \to 0$ , which gives $x \to 0$. As $x \to 0$, $ y \to 0$, hence $f(x,y) \to (0,0)$.

Seems a little vague to me. Can it be improved??

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You havent proven anything yet. Sure, as $(x,mx)\to (0,0)$, you know that $x\to 0$. However, what you must prove is that $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x, mx) = f(0,0)$$
as that is what the question is asking you.

Also, be warned that there exists one line through the origin which cannot be described as $(x,mx)$ for any value of $m$.

Answer (score 0):

If you take your line $(x,mx)$ then you want to see that $x^2\leq mx$ eventually for
$x\to0$.And for $m>0$ this will be the case.  The exceptional case in the $y$ axis and here $f$ is always zero.